# Deployment error on Google App Engine - Uploading 0 files

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

I recently relocated my Eclipse Java GAE project to a different location on my computer. (And both locations are under Dropbox. ) Since then, I've been having issues with deployment. When I make changes to files and save them, sometimes it doesn't recognize the changes and doesn't upload them (so when I deploy through Eclipse, it says uploading 0 files and the live deployment is not updated).

Sometimes it does work (after several clean's and restarts to Eclipse).

Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems solved now, some notes to consider

- Ensure that you are not manually modifying (adding/removing) libraries under war/WEB-INF/lib folder. Add to that folder only when you are using the libraries. (I had some unused libraries there)
- Ensure that war/bin/classes are cleaned after you clean the project
- I reinstalled the plugin as well, just in case